# Chrome auto job apply extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, automation, radio-button, bots

I am working on the chrome extension for auto jobs apply on indeed and encountering this issue.
I'm encountering an issue where, upon entering a number in the input via bot using JavaScript, the text seems to be putted in the text. However, when I subsequently click a continue button on the page, the selected input seems vanished
Is there a way to ensure that the selected input remains in its checked state even after interacting with other elements on the page, such as continue buttons?
this is source code that I am using currently.
I was tried to solve it various ways but always upon clicking the continue button radio input vanished just in search of a solution though which clicking on the continue button input remain same so I can go further

```
 const input = document.querySelector('input[type="number"][value=""]');
    if (input) {
      // Dispatch a keydown event with the key code for "1" (49)
      const event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
        keyCode: 49,
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
        key: "1",
        charCode: 49,
      });
      input.focus(); // Ensure input field is focused
      input.dispatchEvent(event); // Dispatch the keydown event
      console.log('Filled input field with value: 1');
    } else {
      console.log('Input field not found or already filled.');
    }
```

Comment: Try the deprecated document.execCommand, [example](/a/57900849).